# Paypal REST api configuration woes on app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, paypal

I am trying to create an app on google app engine that uses the Paypal REST APIs, but I am having some configuration issues.

In my sdk_config.properties file, I have http.GoogleAppEngine set to true, and my servlet's init method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
    //super.init(servletConfig);
    // ##Load Configuration
    // Load SDK configuration for
    // the resource. This intialization code can be
    // done as Init Servlet.
    InputStream is = AddRecurringPaymentHandler.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/sdk_config.properties");
    try {
        PayPalResource.initConfig(is);
        log.info("Loaded confi successfully!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("Failed to load resource! " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

The initialization succeeds, but when I go into my Post and call the following:

```
String clientId = ConfigManager.getInstance().getValue("clientID");
String clientSecret = ConfigManager.getInstance().getValue("clientSecret");

return new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId, clientSecret).getAccessToken();
```

I get an exception with the following message when run on the dev server (Haven't tested on prod  server yet)

access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/opt/google/google_appengine/java/lib/appengine-tools-api.jar/sdk_config.properties" "read")

Why is it trying to access the file in appengine-tools-api.jar?

It should be noted that ConfigManager.getValue() is deprecated, but this is what is used in all of PayPal's examples and I' not sure what should be used after the deprecation.

**UPDATE**
I tested it on the production server and it still fails with the same exception, but the message returned by the exception is null. What the heck is going on? D:

Comment: i think we need to use:

    ConfigManager.getInstance().getConfigurationMap().get("clientID");

but im running into same issue.

Comment: issue logged: https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java/issues/22

Comment: Thank you, Srinivas! For now, I am just handling the id and secret myself.

Comment: did you get past the issue?

Comment: For the most part. We ended up just rolling our own config solution.